Initial guess in shifted QR algorithm
I'm comparing timings of two implementations of algorithms for the computation of Gauss-Legendre nodes.
1 - The first is a Newton algorithm to find the roots of the Gauss-Legendre polynomials. Quite cleverly, starting values for the algorithm can be cheaply extracted from the root's asymptotic formula.
2 - The second (Golub-Welsch) is a implicitely shifted QR algorithm to find the eigenvalues of a special symmetric tridiagonal matrix build using a three term relation the Legendre polynomials satisfy, which so happen to be the roots I'm looking for. My implementation closely follows tridiag_eigen here: https://github.com/mpmath/mpmath/blob/master/mpmath/matrices/eigen_symmetric.py .
With my current implementations, both algorithms scale quadratically in time (which is to be expected). I'd like to accelerate the second algorithm using the initial guess for the roots, just like I did for the first.
Hence my question : Is there a standard way to use an initial guess for the eigenvalues in the implicit shifted QR algorithm ?
